# Confusion with error-message and error-messages tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-autocomplete

I wanted to put [error-message](/questions/tagged/error-message) in one of the questions I edited. When I typed "error-" there is [error-message](/questions/tagged/error-message) in the suggestion box as expected, but there is also [error-messages](/questions/tagged/error-messages), which is a synonym to [error-message](/questions/tagged/error-message) (as one can see on the screenshot attached).

When I select [error-messages](/questions/tagged/error-messages) and click "learn-more" it opens 36 questions tagged with it (I guess it was made a synonym to [error-message](/questions/tagged/error-message) but somehow questions were not retagged).
Now when I click [about](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/error-messages/info) to open [errors-messages](/questions/tagged/errors-messages) tag wiki, it redirects me to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/error-message/info instead.

So what's going on there? Synonym [error-messages] -> [error-message] seems to work fine, but why is [error-messages](/questions/tagged/error-messages) displayed in the suggestion box? It looks like a bug to me. Is it?

[image: error-messages tag]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what happened here was that the tags was synonymized but not merged, so [error-messages](/questions/tagged/error-messages) still existed but all new uses of it would redirect to [error-message](/questions/tagged/error-message).

I merged [error-messages](/questions/tagged/error-messages) into [error-message](/questions/tagged/error-message). The tag pages are cached, so it might take a bit before you see a change there, but [error-messages](/questions/tagged/error-messages) already no longer shows up as a separate choice when tagging and any attempt to use it will redirect to [error-message](/questions/tagged/error-message).